# LAN speed fluctuations

Tags: local-area-network, network-speed

I am totally out of my depth here, but hopefully someone can at least tell me if what I am seeing is "normal" or not.

I am in the process of migrating a VM from one ESXi host to another via SSH. That process shows me the network speed as things progress. And that network speed has been fluctuating between nearly 100MB/s at the high and as low as 5MB/s on the low end. This is on a Saturday morning when there are no or very few staff in the office (it's an Architecture firm, so there is no time or day when you can with certainty say there is absolutely no one in the office, we are a sick bunch of workaholics). This is potentially an issue because I have also seen large Windows client software installs have issues, where Autodesk installs simply stop, and Autodesk is fairly famous for installers that can not respond to changing network performance. Their "classic deployments" are very specifically not supported over VPN in fact. So I wonder if I have stumbled up on a possible explanation for the number of software install failures we see. But, it is also just as possible that this is just normal network traffic and I am tilting at windmills.
To be clear, the VAST majority of this 1 hr VM copy has been at the high end of that range, but there have been enough moments at the very low end to make me wonder.

For those who need it simplified, the question is; is network speed fluctuating between 5 & 100 MB/S normal, or abnormal?

Comment: and what is the business related question in here? ;) remind you, to edit the question instead of using comments ;)

Comment: What is "normal" depends extremely on your setup - I used to migrate VMs with ~8 Gbit/s. This is not as trivial as you might think. In addition to the network (packet loss rates, congestion) you need to check for storage (RAID controller & cache) or CPU congestion. Without *a lot* of additional information nobody will be able to answer a "why is my server slow" question.

Comment: @zac67 Yeah, I definitely don't expect answers as to WHY. I guess what I am getting at is, is this something that NEEDS to be looked into, or is this something that would potentially be considered normal on a correctly configured network? If a few moments of 5MB/s is normal, I wouldn't worry. If it's a sign of some sort of problem, it's evidence that the IT clowns managing this company are not competent. But, I already know that, they hand out Domain Admin rights like candy.

Comment: If that needs to be looked at depends on your requirements - what are the SLAs? If you're concerned you should test each subsystem separately, not in combination. Run something like iperf3, separate storage read and write tests, CPU load tests and you'll likely see where the root problem lies (if it is one).

Comment: But... I don't know if I SHOULD be concerned or not. Look at it like a car, the car sometimes accelerates quickly and sometimes doesn't. I don't know anything about cars, so I want to know, Is variable acceleration normal? Someone who knows about cars would say "No, that's not normal". If sometimes getting 5% of expected performance is NOT normal, the  we can say to the IT clowns that runs things that they need to figure why it's happening. If it IS normal, then I learned something and I won't complain, about that at least, to the IT clowns. But again, I don't KNOW if it's normal.

Comment: As long as we don't know *anything* about your setup we can't answer the question whether you should be concerned. Please add sufficient detail to your question (server model, storage setup, network setup) and make sure you've checked the [helpcenter/how-to-ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @zac67, I don't HAVE that information. But to rephrase this differently, if you were paying an external IT Consultant say $5,000 a month to manage a network of 200 machines in 4 locations using DFS, and you where seeing network performance like I have described, would you be having words with the consultants, or not concerned? And yeah, I guess the the customer may have agreed to an SLA of "crap" and there is nothing to be done.

Comment: @zac67 so another way to put it, which is definitely not a technical question but a business question, is... Should you sign agree to an SLA that allowes for short duration network throughput of 5% of max, or is that something you should never really have to agree to, because that should never happen with a competently managed network?